# Kdenlive: Pitch compensation doesn't work

Tags: sound, kdenlive

I'm using Kdenlive and speed + pitch compensation. Some years ago it worked correctly, but now sound is distorted. Even when I change speed to 101%, sound is terrible.

Is it only my problem? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Groovy Gorilla, the newest